# A32s fingerprint module pinout

Tags: arduino, fingerprint

I recently bought A32s fingerprint module for work with my arduino uno board, but I couldn't find pinout of that module. Also I actually don't know it's working voltage is 3.3V or 5V.

Previously I worked with FZ2904 fingerprint module and it worked fine. Then I use same pinout for my a32s module, but there are no response of it.

If there anyone had that problem with a32s module and solved it, please help me for my question.

Comment: You will find a better answer by asking your question in https://electronics.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Are you sure about that number? I can find no references to it.

Comment: Yes, I sure the model number. It's on the module.            
                                                            
https://gdfingerprint.com/product/fingerprint-reader-module-a32/#iLightbox[gallery_image_1]/0                                                                 This is a link. There is A32s in those photos, but in that description there is for A32.

Comment: *I actually don't know it's working voltage is 3.3V or 5V.* followed by *Then I use same pinout for my a32s module*. Sure, you might have fried it already.